# I cannot see my selections when editing linked instances

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, instances

fairly new to 3D and Blender.

I am following Chamfer Zones intro to Blender (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2U0MiZSV9A&ab_channel=ChamferZone) and about an hour in the video it shows the creation of instances, and editing of them.

The edits apply to all the models that are instances of the original, but in the tutorial it also displays the verts and selections on all instances. So as an example, he sees Verts on all the instances, and if he selects a vert, it's visibly selected on all instances. On my screen I am not seeing that.

[image: Screenshots of tut and my screen]

If I actually made edits, they do appear on all instances, but I feel like it would be really useful for me to see the selections and verts on all the instances I am editing - a nice visual cue to remind me what's going on. There is probably a difference in settings somewhere, but I am not sure what..

How do I change it so it is in line with the tutorial?

Thank you!

Comment: I think this changed between version 2.93 and 3.0 of Blender but I'm not sure why. - The tutorial is using Blender version 2.90 and presumably you're using 3.6 or 4.0.

Comment: Hi John, I wondered if this might be the case, yes I am using 3.6. I guess there are no viewer options I can change to get the above? 
I am sure there is a good reason this was changed, and maybe I am not experienced enough to see the benefit :3

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with that one. I very rarely use instances so hadn't noticed that change until you mentioned it.